# Printing an Object with ngFor

Tags: angular

I am pulling object from database:

[image]

objects content might be different so we dont know what will come from db.(i mean it might be lemons too)

I am trying to print this using ngfor.If i convert this object to an array i can print it like:

```
this.drops = Object.values(monster[this.randommnumber].drops);

<li *ngFor="let drop of drops">
   {{ drop }}
 </li>
```

this will print
3 and 5 without apple and pixi.

what i am trying to do is print them with their names.(i mean apple:3,pixi:5)

i can do that without converting object to an array and just writing

```
<li *ngFor="let drop of drops">
       Apple:{{ drop.apple }}
       Pixi:{{drop.pixi}}
     </li>
```

but what i am going to do if data has lemons rather than apples?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Write a method to return the property names as you can't use `Object.keys` directly in the html template

```
public getKeys(obj: string[]): any {
      return Object.keys(obj);
}
```

Then, use it to iterate over your object like so,

```
<ul *ngFor="let key of getKeys(obj)">
  <li> {{key}}: {{obj[key]}} </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o3qfgc)

Or, you can also do the below, which is kind of a hack (not recommended)

```
_obj: any = Object;
myObj = {
    apples: 2,
    oranges: 3
}
```

And in your html,

```
<li *ngFor="let key of _obj.keys(y)">
  {{ key }} : {{ myObj[key] }}
</li>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pdduui)

Comment: fun fact: put console.log inside getKeys and see how many times angular calls it. You should never use a function inside an expression cause it's going to be called with every change detection cycle. It can lead to future performance issues

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty simple, just map it as a key value pair

```
Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  template: `
  <li *ngFor="let drop of drops">
  {{ drop.key }} : {{drop.value}}
</li>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent {
  drops: any;
  _drops = {
    apples: 5,
    pixies: 6,
    lemons: 7
  };

  constructor() {
    this.drops = Object.keys(this._drops).map(x => { return { key: x, value : this._drops[x] } });

  }
}
```

also try to find more elegant solution. I'm pretty sure you can make it without using an extra field for that.

Comment: What if `_drops` is modified/reassigned?

Comment: the code from the constructor should be moved to a pipe then